# Texshop : shortcut for renaming environment

Tags: editors, texshop, macos, shortcut

There is a very convenient macro in Emacs+AucteX and I wonder whether it exists in TeXShop. It consists in renaming an environment automatically. Suppose I start with

```
\begin{itemize} 
\item blabla
\item blabla
.... 
\end{itemize}
```

and that I suddenly realize that "enumerate" would be more appropriate than "itemize". Is it possible to hit some keys (with cursor inside the environment to rename) and then to enter "enumerate" and then both occurrences of "itemize" are replaced by "enumerate" ?

Comment: As far as I know, no.